# creating login feature cgi-html in c language.(No PHP,Apache)

Tags: javascript, c++, html, c

I am working in embedded environment. I have Atheros development board. I want to create login page using cgi and html only. I found one library libcgi. I have cross compiled that. I have checked the examples also.

1. how I can use that lib for session handling in login page?
2. Which is better cgi library?

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CGI is a very simple thing: it's an executable that gets some information through stdin and environment variables. The script is executed every time there is a request. The script does not manage any http stuff (like listening on the port 80).

So you most likely will need a http server. There are lots of them, not only apache that will use much less resources.

CGI does not manage sessions at all. You will need a library that does that (however, as a general rule, I would try to avoid web development with sessions. If you need it only for logging in, it's much easier and secure to use authentication with a webserver). As the CGI executables shuts down at the end of a request, it requires some efforts to maintain a state.

Writing CGI in C is rather painful, can't you use any scripting language ? (like python or ruby ?).

Maybe you would be interested in http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/ if you want to expose your application through http.k

Comment: I have only 4 MB of flash right now in board. After that I will get 16 MB flash. I have to learn the scripting language like python or ruby. I am using httpd server. Following process are running in my board. ~ # ps
  724 root         96 S   /usr/sbin/httpd -h /usr/www/ 
Now I have two libraries libcgi and libqdecoder. I have cross compiled them both for my board.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/). It is very good for a web gui of embedded system.

Comment: I have only 4 MB of flash right now in board. After that I will get 16 MB flash. I have to learn the scripting language like python or ruby. I am using httpd server. Following process are running in my board. ~ # ps 724 root 96 S /usr/sbin/httpd -h /usr/www/ Now I have two libraries libcgi and libqdecoder. I have cross compiled them both for my board

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer of this questions. I have prepared one code for it. First of all I want to thank both persons bmeric and Tristram. I have take a look at both the suggestions. microhttpd is quite helpful. But the size of the wt is big so my board does not support it.

Finally let me tell you how I manage the things. In my board as I have already told that httpd is running. Which is part of busybox. Now I have prepared the html pages and java scripts in such a way that it will send the cookie in the header to the server.

My server is accepting the cookie in HTTP_COOKIE environment variable. So I have got it using getEnv function in my code. And based on that I have develop a code for login page.

This is the function call : getenv("HTTP_COOKIE")

Once again thanks.